# I make a telegram bot with telebot in python, but I got an error that I have textbutton, although I have use InlineKeyboardButton, why?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

[image: thats my code in the image]

thats cut of my code:

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) # вывод кнопок в 1 колонку
btn_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(bookmarks_categories[0], callback_data=0)
btn_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(bookmarks_categories[1], callback_data=1)
btn_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(bookmarks_categories[2], callback_data=2)
keyboard.add(btn_1,btn_2,btn_3,btn_4,btn_5,btn_6,btn_7,btn_8,btn_9,btn_10,btn_11,btn_12,btn_13,btn_14,btn_15,btn_16,btn_17)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вывод inline-клавиатуры', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

thats my error:

```
2021-08-28 00:11:29,741 (__init__.py:652 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard"
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Never post code as image. Paste it here

Comment: okay, but really, printing code from python is difficult because stackoverflow considers code indentation as the end of a code section

Comment: Convert indentation to spaces

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, which is for a different library ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this solution, I have done a project by  multiple keyboards such as inline_keyboards and Reply_keyboards, I used telegram library

```
from telegram import (InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup)
```

for inline keyboards buttons you can identify keyboard buttons first in this way:

```
buttons = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=bookmarks_categories[0],callback_data=0),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=bookmarks_categories[1],callback_data=1),
    ],
]
```

then identify your keyboard like this:

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: as I said in my answer you can use telegram library for inline keyboard button and here is it's document: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardmarkup.html?highlight=inline%20keyboard

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass call back data extra for it to work

```
        github.setText("Github ");
        github.setCallbackData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```